# Python Requests -- MemoryError despite using streaming uploads

Tags: python, python-requests

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads), it should be possible to do uploads that are not memory intensive, by giving Request a file-like object rather than the contents of the file. Okay, so I do this in the code:

```
files = {'md5': ('', md5hash),
         'modified': ('', now),
         'created': ('', now),
         'file': (os.path.basename(url), fileobject, 'application/octet-stream', {'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'binary'})}
r = s.post(url, data=content, params=params, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Watching it run on my computer, with a 2.8 GB file, it starts eating up memory at an alarming rate, before it bails out when it reaches about 89% memory used. It then fails with the following output:

```
  File "***.py", line 644, in post
    r = s.post(url, data=content, params=params, files=files, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 424, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 110, in request
    hooks, stream, verify, cert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 348, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 286, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 289, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 426, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 144, in _encode_files
    body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata(new_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 101, in encode_multipart_formdata
    return body.getvalue(), content_type
MemoryError
```

It works okay with smaller files, but still eats up a substantial amount of memory while doing so. Am I misunderstanding something?

### EDIT:

After seeing Martijn Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28198229/161250), I changed my code to this:

```
    files = {'md5': ('', md5hash),
             'modified': ('', now),
             'created': ('', now),
             'file': (os.path.basename(url), fileobject, 'application/octet-stream')}
    m = requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder(fields=files)
    headers['content-type'] = m.content_type
    r = s.post(url, data=m, params=params, headers=headers)
```

I had to remove the `{'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'binary'}`, because it seemed not to be supported, and led to this error message:

```
  File "***.py", line 647, in post
    m = requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder(fields=files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._prepare_parts()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 171, in _prepare_parts
    self.parts = [Part.from_field(f, enc) for f in fields]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 44, in iter_field_objects
    yield RequestField.from_tuples(*field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 97, in from_tuples
filename, data = value
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

(Is there a way to still set this header when using the multipart encoder? I'd much prefer it to be there.)

However, even with removing that header, it's *still* not working, because now I'm getting this error message:

```
  File "***.py", line 647, in post
    r = s.post(url, data=m, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 424, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 114, in request
    main_key = self.cache.create_key(response.request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py", line 156, in create_key
    key.update(_to_bytes(request.body))
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not MultipartEncoder
```

Any ideas? I'll admit that I'm rather new to this and that these error messages are, as they often are in programming, less than helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not streaming the upload because `requests` can only do that if *the whole body* is sourced from an open file object. It'll still read all files into memory to build a multi-part post body.

For multi-part uploads, use the [requests toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/); it includes a [Streaming Multipart Data Encoder](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#uploading-data):

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests

files = {
    'md5': ('', md5hash),
    'modified': ('', now),
    'created': ('', now),
    'file': (os.path.basename(url), fileobject, 'application/octet-stream')
}
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=dict(files, **params))
headers['content-type'] = m.content_type

r = s.post(url, data=m, headers=headers)
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=m, headers=headers)
```

The first argument to `MultipartEncoder` is parsed with the [`iter_field_objects()` function](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.filepost.iter_field_objects) from the `urllib3` library; this means that it can either be a dictionary of key-value pairs, *or* a sequence (list, tuple) of [`RequestField()` objects](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.fields.RequestField).

When passing in a dictionary like I did above, each key-value pair is parsed with [`RequestField.from_tuples()`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.fields.RequestField.from_tuples), and you can only specify the field name, the value, and optionally the filename and the mimetype. Extra headers are not supported. I used that option in the above sample.

If you want to add the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header to the `file` field, then we need to use a sequence of `RequestField` objects:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField

fields = [RequestField.from_tuples(*p) for p in params.iteritems()]
fields.extend([
    RequestField('md5', md5hash),
    RequestField('modified', now),
    RequestField('created', now),
    RequestField(
        'file', fileobject, 'application/octet-stream',
        {'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'binary'}),
])
```

Note that you cannot combine streaming requests with the [request-cache project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache); the latter requires access to the full body of the request to produce a cache key.

You'd have to patch the `requests_cache.backends.base.BaseCache.create_key` method to handle `MultipartEncoder` objects and come up with some kind of hash-key for the body. This is outside the scope of this question however.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right path. I'm sure I can get it to work eventually, but for now, I've run into several hurdles. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Alex; your second error indicates you are using the [requests-cache project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache/0.4.9); you cannot use streaming requests with requests cache as the latter needs the *whole request body* to be able to look up the cached response.

Comment: @Alex: I'm going to punt on the requests-cache issue; without requests-cache the answer should work just fine. We can try and hash out a solution to that problem in a new question perhaps.

Comment: I'll try to disable the cache entirely to see how that goes. I already tried doing `with requests_cache.disabled():` before the call to `post()` without it making a difference. Yep, when I disabled the cache entirely, it worked. I'm very surprised that it wasn't sufficient to do `with requests_cache.disabled():` Regardless, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

simple change in way of uploading file

with open('massive-body', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)

helped